# Remove elements of a vector that are substrings of another

Tags: r, string

Is there a better way to achieve this? I'd like to remove all strings from this vector, which are substrings of other elements.

```
words = c("please can you", 
  "please can", 
  "can you", 
  "how did you", 
  "did you",
  "have you")
> words
[1] "please can you" "please can"     "can you"        "how did you"    "did you"        "have you"

library(data.table)
library(stringr)
dt = setDT(expand.grid(word1 = words, word2 = words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
dt[, found := str_detect(word1, word2)]
setdiff(words, dt[found == TRUE & word1 != word2, word2])
[1] "please can you" "how did you"    "have you"
```

This works, but it seems like overkill and I'm interested to know a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: `CJ` is the much faster `data.table` for `expand.grid`

Comment: Just wanted to put some meat on this for anyone following up. `CJ` is **much** faster. I took `12431` lines with an average of `15.69` words / line for a total set of  `195065` words and ran it through `system.time(dt <- setDT(expand.grid(word1 = words, word2 = words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))` in `user  system elapsed 8.414   3.387  13.854` yet `system.time(dt1 <- CJ(words,words,unique = TRUE))` in `user  system elapsed 0.932   0.365   1.320`. order of magnitude difference.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the benchmark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for each component of `words` in `words` keeping those that occur once:

```
words[colSums(sapply(words, grepl, words, fixed = TRUE)) == 1]
```

giving:

```
[1] "please can you" "how did you"    "have you"
```

Comment: This is great - Thanks a lot!